# Multicolumn text editing?

Tags: javascript, text-editor, multiple-columns

With Microsoft Office Word it is possible to see multiple pages at the same time and while adding new content to the first page, added content will push the content after that forward. Would you say that there exists a preferable solution for achieving similar functionality for a webpage by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript? There might be any amount of pages and not all of them could be shown at the same time.

There is a [multi-column layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) in CSS3, but how about the editing part (and the browser support)?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking. First- do you mean change content on pages that haven't been requested from server yet? Also, what do columns have to do with changing content? Perhaps explaining **`added content will push the content after that forward`** would help

Comment: Focus on what is happening on the client side and forget the server. There can be only so much text on the page one. I can make CSS3 multi-columns editable by setting attribute contenteditable to be "true" (seems to be supported [quite well](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) by the different browsers) for div- and p-tags, but multi-column module itself [aren't supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) won't be implemented in the Internet Explorer until version 10.

Comment: still not explaining what goals are. Columns can be handled with float for browser don't support css3. But you are not explaining the higher level issues... and please define "page"

Comment: After taking another look at what I've just said, it is truely possible that there is room for some clarification. 'Page' referred to pages in a Word-document.

Answer (score 0):

It works with the CSS multicolumns just like you said. I did a wiki-like website that uses multicolumn layout and contenteditable to edit the text. I've noticed that Chrome sometimes has issues handling it (the tab crashes) but Firefox handles it fine. It will probably be fixed.

Another interesting solution is (still as a working-draft) CSS regions and "flow-into" rule.